# angularjs ui-router location path not recognizing the forward slahes

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm using [angular ui router / stateProvider](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router). However I set up my url any parts after the second forward slash is ignored and it always sends to this state:

```
  $stateProvider.state('board', {
    url: "/:board",
    views: {
      'content': {
        templateUrl: '/tmpl/board',
        controller: function($scope, $stateParams, $location) {
          console.log('wat')
          console.log($location)
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

Which has only 1 forward slash. Even when I go to `localhost/contacts/asdf` The following state doesn't run.

$stateProvider.state('test', {
    url: "/contacts/asdf",
    views: {
      'main': {
        templateUrl: '/tmpl/contacts/asdf',
        controller: function () {
          console.log('this doesnt work here')
        }
      }
    }
  });

[image: console ss]
This is a console log of $location. As you can see $location only recognizes the last part of the url as the path. As far as I can tell that's wrong. It's missing the "contacts" right before it. Any url is interpreted as having only 1 part for the url and sends to the `board` state. How do I fix this. THanks.

Edit: found that this was caused by angular 1.1.5. Reverting back to 1.1.4 didn't have this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be the cause: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2799 .  Try adding a base href.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like that fixed in [AngularJS v1.0.7](https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.0.7/angular.js). Just tested it.