# How should I use Angular UI Router?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, single-page-application, angular-ui

I have searched the Internets for a couple of days, but can't find what I'm looking for.

I am building an SPA using angularjs but I'm struggling with something I think should be quite basic. Coming from a `ASP.NET MVC` mindset, I am trying to set up routes for listing data and creating new data, for example:

```
.state('placements', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/placements',
    template: '<div ui-view></div>'
})
.state('placements.list', {
    url: '',
    templateUrl: mapPathToViews('placements.list'),
    controller: 'PlacementController'
})
.state('placements.new', {
    url: '/new',
    templateUrl: mapPathToViews('placements.new'),
    controller: 'PlacementController'
})
```

So with these states set up, I would think that navigating to `/placements/new` would give me the "new placements" view.

**This works perfectly if I use the ui-sref navigation**

The problem comes from when I type `myapp.com/placements/new` into a browser and hit GO, no route is matched at all. However, if I go to `myapp.com/placements` I see the correct view as expected.

My question is this: Am I right in how I think the router should be set up or do I need to have a completely separate state for new placements, such as `myapp.com/newplacement`?

### Update

It seems to be something to do with the way ui-router figures out the state on first page load. If I load the page with the url `myapp.com/placements/new`, then click on a navigation item which points to a state with the url of `'/'` (meaning home page, right?) then the url becomes `myapp.com/placements/` and the view for the home page is rendered. Similarly, if I click another nav link pointing to `'/somewhereelse'` the url becomes `myapp.com/placements/somewhereelse` and the `somewhereelse` view is rendered. I'm guessing then that when it loads `/placements/new` it (for some reason) is actually looking for a root state with the url of `/new` which doesn't exist.

This is proven when I add `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/not-found');` and reload the page at `/placements/new`, the url becomes `myapp.com/placements/not-found`.

Is this a bug? (sorry, undocumented feature) or have I got something wrong here?

### Another Update.

Ok, this is doing my head in now.

I figured I'd have a go at hacking something to get around this, and thought I'd get away with adding a `/new` state and just calling `$state.transitionTo('placements.new')` and all will be well. Turns out that if I do that, the url becomes `myapp.com/placements/placements/new` - wtf?

Comment: Shouldnt you be assigning url for 'placements.new' as '/placements/new' ?

Comment: No, because there is an `abstract` state which is the parent state so the Url becomes `/placements/new` by magic.

Comment: Does it work without the mapToView calls? Like if you just inline some templates?

Comment: No, that mapToViews is just a function that concatenates a string with the passed in values. Like I say, this all works nicely when I use ui-sref or $state.transitionTo() but not if I reload the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

I changed what I was searching for and found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16781447/773208) which lead me to [this issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/2799). Long story short, I added `<base href="/" />` to my index.html and voila, all is working well.